# How to override make the save method of the Model working depends on a specific field changing in Django?

Tags: python, django

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.status == 1:
            ... 
            count + 1
            ...
        else:
            pass
```

I override the save() method in the Model, what I wanna to implement is:

**if the "status"(default value equals 0) changes from 0 to 1, then "count + 1"**

So, there are 4 conditions during saving:

- "status" changes from 0 to 1: count + 1
- "status" changes from 1 to 0: pass
- "status" equals 0 not change: pass
- "status" equals 1 not change: pass

With my implementation, everyone works well but the last one, the "count + 1" still runs when the "status" not change, from 1 to 1 (which means has not been edited) during saving.

I tried self.id, self._state.adding, etc, but failed.

What should I do to keep the last condition going correct?

Need your help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can query old status from DB before saving:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):        
    if self.pk: # If object is not new
        old_record = MyModel.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
            if old_record.status == 0 and self.status == 1: # If status changed
                count + 1
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```